# Java - create a php file, execute it and get output

Tags: java, php, r.java-file

In the JAVA application I'm developping, I need to execute on the server side a piece of PHP code sent by the client.
I found some intresting libraries but they don't return the output when there are syntax errors.
As an alternative, I thought of creating a php file, adding the content to it, then execute it using ubuntu command lines.

What I don't really know, is how to get the output of the execution, and when executing the code using terminal, what's the path of the php file that I created in java.

If you have any other ideas that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Java but if you're going to execute php using terminal then you can use standard output redirection

```
php fileThatYouUploaded.php > someTemporaryFileToGetOutput.txt 2> tempFileWithErrorsIfAny.txt
```

or if you want the output and errors in the same file:

```
php fileThatYouUploaded.php > someTemporaryFileWithOutputAndErrors.txt 2>&1
```

As a side note: trusting a code from a user is a *very bad idea*. You would be better with some kind of library that will allow you to whitelist/blacklist functions and classes or even run it in closed/sandboxed environment.

Comment: Yeah that's for sure, I will take care of the security aspect after by isolating the part where the code is being executed.
Thanks